# intergrate live group chat in node js web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, livechat

I have developed a web application using node and backbone js which is in beta now. Now my client wants group chat to be integrated in that application. This chat should take place between users that are signed in to application. Is there any chatting tool that can help me to achieve this? Or I need to implement this by myself? I have never integrated chat in any web application before. I tried to google about customer-to-customer chatting tools but did not get any tool that can help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using node you can check socket.io for implementing real-time communication between users of your application. With node and socket.io out-of-the-box functionality exists for separating users into rooms for group chatting (and broadcasting)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I haven't worked with socket.io yet and I need to integrate chat within two days. Does any module/library exists that can do things little simple for me?

Comment: With socket.io you will be up and running in two days for sure. Just install the module and follow an online tutorial.

Comment: I also need to maintain chat history. Writing everything from scratch is not going to be that easy. Some library must exist for sure.